# Designing web pages that respond to browser font settings

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

A coworker of mine noticed that a page I had built was displaying incorrectly because he had increased his font size in Chrome to "large".

I realized that I had not specified a default font for the page. When I did this, it overrode his browser settings and displayed the text at the size I had specified. Now, he can see the page, but the text is not the large font that he wanted.

Is it possible to design the page in such a way that my divs and containers respond to browser settings like this? In other words, is there a way to increase the size of a div IF the user has increased their default font size in their browser settings?

My instincts tell me this is impossible, because CSS media queries respond to window size. I'm hoping someone can either enlighten me on this topic or confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way fonts (and many, many other things) in web development and CSS work is that you write CSS to *suggest* to the browser how things should look. The browser is free to implement your suggestions (and normally will, 95% of the time, provided they make sense), but is also free to ignore them. Fonts are hard because, (1.) they are high on the list of things browsers might ignore, (2.) there is a very small subset of fonts that can reliably be expected to exist on all devices, and (3.) there aren't any 100% solutions to displaying any arbitrary font on any arbitrary device via the web yet.

That said, it sounds like these are the concepts you may be most interested in learning:

- [EM width](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/): The `em` is a width basically representing the width of the letter `m` in the user's font. This, as well as percentages (which have some major pitfalls), allow you to specify relative font sizes.
- [Font stacks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-stacks/), which are CSS declarations that try to give a consistent look across pages by declaring similar Fonts in a list that the browser can either display or fall back to until it runs out of choices and displays a default.
- [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to give yourself a blank slate. There are various implementations of this, but a reset CSS is attempting to normalize the various differences in default CSS across the various major browsers.

Comment: Pay attention to line-height as well, making sure you test short headlines for possible line breaks and use `1.4` etc for the heights so that they are relative.

Answer (score 0):

If you set all sizes based on ems and rems instead of pixels or points then everything will be done relative to the font size the user sets. This allows the user to pick their default font size and to have everything resize around that.